# update a currently displayed variable

Tags: python

I am writing some Python code, which will in the end will display something which looks like:

```
Volt1:  3.1V  
Volt2:  2.6V  
Volt3:  5.6V
```

I am constantly monitoring some register values which will give me the current values of Volt1,Volt2,Volt3.  As I read in the new values I want to update the field next to the variable name (i.e 3.1V becomes 3.12V), but without just simply printing a new line, but updated the old value.

I am just not sure how to do it, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is best handled using a library such as [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).